# Find next select element inside class

Tags: jquery

I have something like the following HTML:

```
<div class="someClass">
    <div>
        <span>first</span><select id="first"></select>
        <span>second</span><select id="second"></select>
    </div>
    <div>
        Some text...
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>third</span><select id="third"></select>
        <span>fourth</span><select id="fourth"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want with jquery, on change one select element, find (fill with options) next select element.
Something like this:

```
$(".someClass").on("change", "select", function(){
    $(this).closest(".someClass").find("select").next();
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/next/  itself it will be so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of whenever you change one option, a new option is added to the next select.

```js
$('select').change(function () {
    var idx = $('div.someClass select').index(this);
    $('div.someClass select').eq(idx + 1).append('<option>3</option>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someClass">
    <div> <span>first</span>

        <select id="first">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select> <span>second</span>

        <select id="second">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>Some text...</div>
    <div> <span>third</span>

        <select id="third">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select> <span>fourth</span>

        <select id="fourth">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can try this, more easy:

```
 $("div select").on( "change",function() {
    var sel = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find("select").val(sel);
})
```